# Change colour of NavigationView Title SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swiftui, navigationview

Is it possible to change the colour of a NavigationView Title?

I have done this:

```
NavigationView
{
    Form
    {
        // Form Stuff
    }
    .navigationBarTitle(Text("Profile").color(Color.white))
}
```

However the title remains black, I have looked at the docs and there is apparently a property called `navigationViewStyle` I don't even know if this would help but no matter where I put it it says its not a member of Navigation View and docs are blank for basically the entire class... so anyone managed to figure this out yet??

Ideally I would also change the Font too so it matched the rest of my app, but since it just seems to ignore any tags set to the Text object im assuming this is not how it is supposed to be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `UINavigationBar.appearance()` for that,

Check below code:

```swift
    struct ContentView : View {

        init() {
            UINavigationBar.appearance().largeTitleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor:UIColor.green]
            UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor:UIColor.green]
        }

        var body: some View {
          NavigationView {
              Form {
              // Form Stuff
              }
             .navigationBarTitle(Text("Profile"))
             }
          }
       }
    }
```

Comment: I’m not sure this is entirely the correct answer, since SwiftUI is meant to be platform / implementation agnostic. This code wouldn’t work on macOS for instance

Comment: @BlueSpud yes, you are right, in the near future, I hope SwiftUI has some solution for that.